# Не считывает файл до конца?

Tags: c++

Необходимая инфа(файл) для работы проги message.txt

```
Business process, activities that produce a specific service or product for 
customers
Business process modeling, activity of representing processes of an 
enterprise in order 
Manufacturing process management, a collection of technologies and methods 
used to define.
Process architecture, structural design of processes, applies to fields such 
as computers.
Process costing, a cost allocation procedure of managerial accounting
Process management, ensemble of activities of planning and monitoring the 
performance of .
Process management (Project Management) , a systematic series of activities 
directed .
Process-based management, is a management approach that views a business as 
a collection .
Process industry, a category of material-related industry.

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//#include <io.h> 
//#include <stdlib.h>   
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
#define N 8
#define F32 0xFFFFFFFF
#define size64 sizeof(uint64_t)
#define ROR(x,n,xsize)((x>>n)|(x<<(xsize-n)))
#define ROL(x,n,xsize)((x<<n)|(x>>(xsize-n)))
#define RKEY(r)((ROR(K,r*3,size64*8))&F32)
const uint64_t K = 0x96EA704CFB1CF672;//base key to forming of round keys
uint32_t RK[N];//massive round keys
#define CBC 0
#define CFB 0
#if CBC == 1 && CFB ==0
    const uint64_t IV = 0x296EA704CFB1CF67;
#endif
void createRoundKeys(bool print)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        RK[i]=(ROR(K, i * 8, size64 * 8))&F32;
        if (print)
             std::cout << "key[" << i << "]=" << std::hex << RK[i] <<std::endl;
    }
}
uint32_t F(uint32_t subblk, uint32_t key)
{
    /*
    uint32_t f1 = ROL(subblk, 9, sizeof(subblk) * 8);
    uint32_t f2 = ROR(key, 11, sizeof(key) * 8) | subblk;
    return f1 ^ !f2;
    */
    return subblk+key;
}
//encryption 64-digit block of message
uint64_t encrypt(uint64_t block, bool print)
{
    //select subblocks
    uint32_t left = (block >> 32)&F32;
    uint32_t right = block&F32;

    uint32_t left_, right_;//subblock in the end of round
    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++)
    {
        if (print)
            std::cout << "round " << r << std::endl << "input blks " << std::hex << left << " " << right << std::endl;
        uint32_t fk = F(left, RK[r]);
        left_ = left;
        right_ = right^fk;
        if (r < N - 1)//swap places to next round
        {
            left = right_;
            right = left_;
        }
        else//last round not swap
        {
             left = left_;
            right = right_;
        }
        if (print)
            std::cout << "round" << r << std::endl << "output blks " << std::hex << left << " " << right << std::endl;
    }
    //collect subblock in block
    uint64_t c_block = left;
    c_block = (c_block << 32) | (right&F32);
    return c_block;
}
//decryption 64-digit block of message
uint64_t decrypt(uint64_t c_block, bool print)
{
     //select subblocks
     uint32_t left = (c_block >> 32)&F32;
    uint32_t right = c_block&F32;

    uint32_t left_, right_;//subblock in the end of round
    for (int r = N-1; r >=0; r--)
    {
        if (print)
            std::cout << "round " << r << std::endl << "input blks " << std::hex << left << " " << right << std::endl;
        uint32_t fk = F(left, RK[r]);
        left_ = left;
        right_ = right^fk;
        if (r > 0)//swap places to next round
        {
            left = right_;
            right = left_;
        }
        else //last round not swap
        {
            left = left_;
            right = right_;
        }
        if (print)
            std::cout << "round" << r << std::endl << "output blks " << std::hex << left << " " << right << std::endl;
    }
    //collect subblock in block
    uint64_t block = left;
    block = (block << 32) | (right&F32);
    return block;
 }
 #pragma warning(disable:4996)
 void main()
 {
    std::cout << "Base key\n" <<std::hex<<K<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nRound keys:" << std::endl;
createRoundKeys(false);


FILE *fp,*fencrypted,*fdecrypted;
char str[N];
if ((fp=fopen("message.txt", "r" ))==NULL) {
    std::cout<<"Cannot open file.\n";
    exit (1);
}

std::vector<uint64_t> *msg = new std::vector<uint64_t>(),
    *plaintext = new std::vector<uint64_t>();//plain text

unsigned long long id;

char ch;
int countbyte = 0;
std::cout << "Message:\n";
int countpb1 = 0,ct1=0, countpb2 = 0,ct2=0;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    if (countbyte % N == 0 && countbyte!=0)
    {
        countbyte = 0;
        memcpy(&id, str, N);
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        msg->push_back(id);
        countpb1++;
        for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
            str[i] = '\0';
    }
    str[countbyte] = ch;
    std::cout << str[countbyte];
    countbyte++;
    ct1++;
}
memcpy(&id, str, N);
msg->push_back(id);

//uint64_t msg = 0xFFAADD11CCBB2299;//plain text

fclose(fp);
printf("\nCountPB1=%i\n", countpb1);
printf("\nCt1=%i\n", ct1);
if ((fencrypted = fopen("cryptmessage.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
    //printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    std::cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
    exit(1);
}
if ((fdecrypted = fopen("message2.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
    //printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    std::cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
    exit(1);
}
#if CBC == 1 && CFB == 0
    uint64_t iv = IV;
#endif

int ii = 0;
uint64_t cipher;
for (std::vector<uint64_t>::iterator it = msg->begin(); it != msg->end(); ++it)
{
    //std::cout << "msg:\n" << std::hex << *it << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "msg:\n" << std::hex << msg << std::endl;
    //uint64_t cipher = encrypt(msg, true);//change on true second parameter when debug, ciphertext
 #if CBC == 0 && CFB == 0
    cipher = encrypt(msg->at(ii), false);
 #endif
 #if CBC == 1 && CFB ==0
    cipher = encrypt(msg->at(ii) ^ iv, false);//change on true second parameter when debug, ciphertext
    iv = cipher;
 #endif
 #if CBC == 0 && CFB == 1
 #endif
    //std::cout << "encrypt:\n" << cipher << std::endl;
    memcpy(str, &cipher, N);
    //fwrite(str, N, 1, fencrypted);
    int i = -1;
    while (++i < N/*strlen(str)*/)
    {
        fputc(str[i], fencrypted);
    }
    ii++;
}
fclose(fencrypted);
#if CBC == 1 && CFB ==0
iv = IV;
#endif
if ((fencrypted = fopen("cryptmessage.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    //printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    std::cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
    exit(1);
}
countbyte = 0;
while (!feof(fencrypted))
{
    (ch = fgetc(fencrypted));// != -1/*EOF*/
    bool b = false;
    if (ct2 == 186)
        b = true;
    if (countbyte % N == 0 && countbyte != 0)
    {
        countbyte = 0;
        memcpy(&id, str, N);
        plaintext->push_back(decrypt(id, false));

 #if CBC == 1 && CFB ==0
        plaintext->at(plaintext->size()-1) ^= iv;
        iv = plaintext->at(plaintext->size() - 1);
 #endif
        countpb2++;
    }
    str[countbyte] = ch;
    std::cout << str[countbyte];
    countbyte++;
    ct2++;      
}
std::cout << "\nCountPB2=" << countpb2 << "\n";
printf("\nCt2=%i\n", ct2);
ii = 0;
for (std::vector<uint64_t>::iterator it = plaintext->begin(); it != plaintext->end(); ++it)
{

    //msg = decrypt(cipher, true);//change on true second parameter when debug,plain text

    //plaintext->push_back(decrypt(cipher, false));//change on true second parameter when debug,plain text

    memcpy(str, &plaintext->at(ii), N);
    int i = -1;
    while (++i < N/*strlen(str)*/)
    {
        fputc(str[i], fdecrypted);
    }
    //fwrite(str,N,1, fdecrypted);

    //std::cout << "decrypt:\n" << msg<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "decrypt:\n" <<str/*plaintext->at(ii)*/<< "\n--------------------------\n" << std::endl;
    ii++;
}
fclose(fencrypted);
fclose(fdecrypted);

system("pause");
}
```

Проблема в том что файл зашифрованный cryptmessage.txt не считывается до конца, поскольку кол-во push_back'ов при считывании message.txt countpb1 != countpb2 94!=34 из файла cryptmessage.txt Помогите срочно нужно,не бойтесь что там лютая крипта, проблема в считывании файлов, потому как кол-во считанных символов ct1!=ct2 то есть ct1 = 754 ,a ct2=418 а должно быть равно одно другому потому как алгоритмы считывания одинаковы

Comment: Ошибка вот в этом -- `char ch;` Нужно `int ch;`

Comment: не помогло тоже самое до конца не читается

Answer (score 1):

```
fencrypted = fopen("cryptmessage.txt", "wb")) == NULL
fencrypted = fopen("cryptmessage.txt", "rb")
```

Всего лишь добавить b для бинарного чтения-записи